# Rcpp: confusion about the base operation of assignment

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Recently, I am trying to work on the Rcpp package to improve efficiency of computation in my work. However,I am not deep knowledged about C++, there are some strange behavoirs I can not understand. The below example show a simple tasks about derving weight of NumericVector, there are several questions:

1. When I use WAP=rev(WAP), it results in an incorrect output, I have to introduce a new variable to store the result so that I get the right output. I do not know why, should it NEVER use a 'x=f(x)' operation in C++ and Rcpp (must copy by clone instead) ?
2. About the CharacterVector method="eq", exactly I want to use a char or string type, however, it does not work with strncmp function (now I have to use method[0]), but I do not know how to look up the API of Rcpp functions in Rstudio?
3. I wonder whether there is a R-style grep, tolower function for conditions in Rcpp, I do not know which document I should refer to except for Rcpp suger, so that I can find the availiable base functions. Otherwise, I am thinking about calling R functions with Rcpp::function R_grep("grep"), but I do know whether this is the best way and recommended.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cppweight(int N, CharacterVector method="eq", const bool reverse=false, const bool test=false){
  NumericVector W(N);
  NumericVector WAP(N);
  NumericVector revWAP(N);
  //method=tolower(method); //function not exists

  if(strncmp(method[0],"eq",2)==0){
    W=rep(1,N)/1.0*N;//convert int to float by multiplying 1.0 
    WAP=W/sum(W);
    Rcout<< sum(W) << "\n";
  } else if(strncmp(method[0],"ln",2)==0){
    W=rev(seq(1,N))/1.0*N;
    WAP=W/sum(W);
  }
  if(reverse){
    if(test){
      WAP=rev(WAP);//Why this result in incorrect result
      revWAP=WAP;
    }else{
      revWAP=rev(WAP);
    }
  }else{
    revWAP=WAP;
  }
  return(round(revWAP,3));
}

/*** R
cppweight(6,"ln",reverse=F,test=F)
cppweight(6,"ln",reverse=T,test=F)
cppweight(6,"ln",reverse=T,test=T)
  */
```

Comment: Don't take it personally but this is a) your third question in a few days, yet you haven't bothered accepting answers to your earlier questions abd b) somewhat close to 'write code for me as mine doesn't work' which is one of the reasons why questions get closed.  For both reasons you may not get as many answers as you hope for.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, Sorry for doing this. I am a researcher not a programmer, so that I am not familiar with the votes and reputation mechanism about stackoverflow before. I was so eager to solve the problem at hand that I ignored the rules of the forum. However, except for 'write code for me as mine doesn't work', I am also trying to ask for help about where I can learn from. All in all, thanks for your reminder and kindly response.

Comment: There is ample help here at StackOverflow on a) how the site works, b) how to ask a good question (see eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and c) of course 2k+ examples of prior Rcpp questions giving you an idea about what worked and what doesn't.  Your excuse of "sorry, but I am busy and don't have time" applies equally to the volunteers whose help you are seeking here.  Help us help you.  I would start by maybe deleting this question and asking a single (rather than three) focussed question, preferably with (shorter) code showing what you tried and expected.

Comment: I think @DirkEddelbuettel is right that there are ample resources on how the site works, and that "I'm busy" isn't really an excuse not to look at them. You're asking for our time, it's only fair that you take your time to understand how the site works before using it. However, I disagree about splitting the question into 3 as I see a common thread running through them: `Rcpp` provides a seamless integration of R and C++, meaning that if you want to get the most out of it, you have to learn *at least a little* about C++ first.

Comment: There are straight forward solutions to your problems and answers to your questions. I would request first though that you *at least* provide an [mcve] by [edit]ing your question to include your expected output of the R calls to the function at the end there.